# Drupal 7 - How can we debug SQL query errors

Tags: drupal-7

I am new to Drupal, and while interacting with database sometimes I get this error:

```
Error
The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.
```

How do I debug this issue?
How can I can see which and what query is causing the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [Drupal Devel Module](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel). After enabling it, in the config page (Admin > Configuration > Development > Development Options) you should check the first option.

[image]

Checkbox that should be selected (sorry, mine is in Spanish!)

Then, you will see a list of queries to the database every time you load a page. The time needed to perform the query is also shown. This way you can identify which queries have a bad performance.

[image]

Hope it helps